# Why is the CreatedAt property nullable in azure mobile services?

Tags: entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

Each time I add or update my an entity in Azure mobile services, the UpdatedAt property has some value. So why is it nullable anyway?

Comment: "Why" questions regarding libraries are always hard to answer and tend to be highly opinion-based.

Comment: I am not so sure. There maybe circumstances where this value (automatically generated) is null. I never experienced that. But maybe a more experienced developer can explain when this is the case and what the reason for this is.

Answer (score 2):

Automatically generated columns are nullable to make upgrade easier.

If you're using the JavaScript Backend & the Todo quickstart application, you'll note that it doesn't contain any columns, but then, if you deploy the client application and insert a new item, it will then create some new columns.